# Is it possible to create templated user-defined literals (literal suffixes) for string literals?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I was suprised when I discovered that it's possible to make user-defined literals templated:

```
template <char ...C> std::string operator ""_s()
{
    char arr[]{C...};
    return arr;
}

// ...

std::cout << 123_s;
```

But above declaration does not work with string literals:

```
"123"_s
```

gives me following error:

> *prog.cpp:* In function 'int main()':
>   *prog.cpp:12:15:* error: no matching function for call to 'operator""_s()'
>     std::cout << "123"_s;
>
> *prog.cpp:4:34:* note: candidate: template std::string operator""_s()
>    template  std::string operator ""_s()
>
> *prog.cpp:4:34:* note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

[(Ideone)](http://ideone.com/WTNxyh)

Is there is a way to use templated user-defined literals with string literals as well?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Note you cannot do `<< foo_s;` either, no need for quotes to make it fail.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I know. Of course that's not a real use case. I want to be able to generate a unique type based on a string literal and that could be one of the possible ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-C++20 it's impossible in standard C++. Refer to [@T.C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40920268/2752075) for a non-standard solution that works with GCC and Clang.

---

Starting with C++20, you can pass string literals as template parameters. You need a helper class like this one:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string_view>

namespace impl
{
    // Does nothing, but causes an error if called from a `consteval` function.
    inline void ExpectedNullTerminatedArray() {}
}

// A string that can be used as a template parameter.
template <std::size_t N>
struct ConstString
{
    char str[N]{};

    static constexpr std::size_t size = N - 1;

    [[nodiscard]] std::string_view view() const
    {
        return {str, str + size};
    }

    consteval ConstString() {}
    consteval ConstString(const char (&new_str)[N])
    {
        if (new_str[N-1] != '\0')
            impl::ExpectedNullTerminatedArray();
        std::copy_n(new_str, size, str);
    }
};
```

It allows you to do this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <ConstString S>
void Print()
{
    std::cout << S.view() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Print<"foo">();
}
```

This might be enough for your use case, and you might not need template UDLs per se.

But if you do need them, it's possible:

```
#include <iostream>

template <ConstString S>
void operator""_print()
{
    std::cout << S.view();
}

int main()
{
    "foo"_print;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Clang and GCC support an extension that allows you to do

```
template<class CharT, CharT... Cs>
std::string operator ""_s() { return {Cs...}; }
```

But there is nothing in standard C++; proposals to standardize this have been made several times and rejected each time, most recently less than a month ago, mostly because a template parameter pack is a *really* inefficient way to represent strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it it's that inefficient, then why do we have templated version for number literals?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The original rationale was that they are useful with `constexpr` for compile-time computation. Also, it doesn't hurt that those literals are generally short and that they were standardized at a time when there was no implementation (so the compile-time cost wasn't necessarily apparent).

Comment: Standard committee doesn't want me to have a compile-time C++ compiler.  Spoilsports.

Comment: Can you link to any documentation of this extension? Does it have a name?

Comment: @eric `-Wgnu-string-literal-operator-template`