# How do you define user-defined string literal operator templates in C++17?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, clang++, string-literals

According to my [(draft) version of C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) (16.5.8 [over.literal]) as well as as [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), C++17 *should* have support for templated operators for user-defined string literals.

Specifically:

```
template <char...>
double operator "" _pi() {
    return 0.;
}

int main() {
  "test"_pi;
}
```

However, both gcc and clang yell at me:

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17
error: no matching function for call to 'operator""_pi<char, 't', 'e', 's', 't'>()'
    7 |   "test"_pi;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
note: candidate: 'template<char ...<anonymous> > double operator""_pi()'
    2 | double operator "" _pi() {

// clang -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17
error: no matching literal operator for call to 'operator""_pi' with arguments of types 'const char *' and 'unsigned long', and no matching literal operator template
```

([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qjE6PsEqr))

They both seem to want to nudge me towards the following template, which used be briefly considered to be part of C++17, but to my understanding did not become part of it:

```
template <typename T, T...>
double operator "" _pi() {
    return 0.;
}
```

However, both gcc and clang correctly *warn* that this is a non-standard extension but they compile it correctly. Both [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) and [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) claim to have full support of the C++17 core language.

What am I doing wrong? Is my draft *AND* cppreference.com inaccurate? I currently don't have access to the final standard version.

---

### Use case

My use case is to implement the following, which is why I need the compile time information.

```
template <char... cs>
constexpr auto operator "" _a() {
  return std::array<char, sizeof...(cs)>({cs...});
}
// "Hello"_a creates a std::array<char,5>
```

Comment: See [Is it possible to create templated user-defined literals (literal suffixes) for string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920149/is-it-possible-to-create-templated-user-defined-literals-literal-suffixes-for)

Comment: @cpplearner Interesting. But that seems to be a pre-C++17 answer, where, indeed, this wasn't part of the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template `char...` user defined literal is not for strings.  It is called a numeric literal operator template and it allows you to have a literal operator that will take the number you are using and expand it into a pack for the template operator.  For example, you would use your operator like

```
1234_pi
```

and that would resolve to calling

```
operator "" <'1', '2', '3', '4'> _pi()
```

What you'd like to have is not possible in stock C++17

To get this to work, you'll need to upgrade to C++20, which lets you use a user defined type that can be constructed from a string literal, and use that to build the `std::array`.  This is what is now called a string literal operator template.
That would look like

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct MakeArray
{
    std::array<char, N> data;
    
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr MakeArray(const char (&arr)[N], std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Is...>) : data{arr[Is]...} {}
 
    constexpr MakeArray(char const(&arr)[N]) : MakeArray(arr, std::make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>())
    {}
};
 
template<MakeArray A>
constexpr auto operator"" _foo()
{
    return A.data;
}
```

and then

```
"test"_foo;
```

and that will resolve to a `std::array<char, 5>`.  If you don't want the null terminator in the array, You just need to subtract `1` from `N` everywhere it is used except for the `char const(&arr)[N]` parts.

If you can't use C++20, you could switch this over to a couple of functions like

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto as_array_helper(const char (&arr)[N], std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Is...>)
{
    return std::array<char, N>{arr[Is]...};
}

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto as_array(const char (&arr)[N])
{
    return as_array_helper(arr, std::make_integer_sequence<std::size_t, N>());
}
```

and then you would use it like

```
as_array("test")
```

Comment: But, even in C++20, we cannot have an UDL which returns a char sequence :-/ (to pass compile time string)

Comment: That explains why I was allowed to define the operator, but not use it as intended. Good explanation of my misconception +1

Comment: Does anybody know if UDLs returning char sequences will ever become a standard C++ feature? For example in C++23? GCC and Clang already support it, so it can definitely be done and I see no reason why it should not become "standard" given its usefulness!