# C++17: turn raw-string into char parameter pack with user-defined-literals

Tags: c++, c++17

This way of defining the `operator""` compiles in gcc

```
template<char... Str>
struct compile_time_string {};

template<char... Str>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, compile_time_string<Str...> str)
{ return ((os << Str), ...); }

template<class T, T... Str>
inline constexpr auto operator""_test() noexcept
{ return compile_time_string<Str...>{}; }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "hi"_test << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Clang also accepts it but issues the warning saying that it's a gnu extension:

> warning: string literal operator templates are a GNU extension [-Wgnu-string-literal-operator-template]

I see that, in C++23, clang still emits the same warning ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MEfYxWdbq)), which means that this syntax is still not valid nowadays.

Is there any proposal or plans to allow that syntax in C++ standard? Is there any standard way to turn a string literal into a char parameter pack, or that gnu extension is the only way nowadays?

Comment: No, that extension was rejected from the standard but there is another (albeit somewhat roundabout) way to get the characters as a template parameter pack. You can define a structural type template with a constexpr constructor taking a char array reference (`const char(&str)[N]`), deduce `N`, and then use TMP to get the parameter pack from the NTTP structural type. The UDL signature is then `template <auto N> struct char_array { constexpr char_array(const char(&str)[N]) noexcept; }; template <char_array Arr> inline constexpr auto operator""_test() noexcept;`

Comment: Will post later if someone else doesn't beat me to the punch.

Comment: I see you have it labeled C++17, but the overload I'm referring to was added in C++20: [See 3) a.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) **edit** my point is, do you still want the answer if it's only allowed in C++20? Or are you just looking for the answer that, in C++17, there is no standard way to obtain the characters as a pack?

Comment: [How do you define user-defined string literal operator templates in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67021626/how-do-you-define-user-defined-string-literal-operator-templates-in-c17)

Comment: What language version are you targeting? The tag says C++17, you're mentioning C++23 in the question body. There's a different, standard way of doing this in C++20 or newer.